# How can i give app store link in my apps before approving another apps

Tags: iphone

I have two version of apps with lite and paid. I have another apps also but no one is approved yet. I want to give my all the apps link in my life version and all the apps are not approved yet.

So how can i give apps store link in my apps for another apps which are not approved yet.

Please anyone have idea?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

I use this pattern: `https://itunes.apple.com/app/id<app_apple_id>`.
I think it's more reliable way than using app name.

Comment: Note: you can get your App Ids from the developer provisioning portal (APp IDs). You can do this before the App is approved and it will still work if you change the name of your app.

Comment: ID is not located in "provisioning portal" its located in iTunesConnect, there you can find the app id.

Answer (score 21):

`itms://itunes.com/apps/AppName` works, but `itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/AppName` will save your users having to do the redirect through the iTunes app. Instead, the `itms-apps` protocol will open the app store directly, thus sparing your users the unnecessary wait.

Comment: I guess this changed subtly since 2010 … nowadays it’s `itms-apps://itunes.com/app/AppName` (**app** instead of **apps**). It’s probably also safer to use `itunes.apple.com` for the domain.

Answer (score 17):

You can try using `http://itunes.com/apps/your_app_name`

[Try it out](http://itunes.com/apps/ambiance)

Answer (score 4):

This is the way I used for PocketCAS and PocketCAS pro:

I added to PocketCAS a link to somewhere on my website, e.g. http://pocketcas.com/iphone/buy, which will, as soon as PocketCAS pro has been approved, point to the corresponding App Store link. This also has the advantage that I could easily replace the App Store link by a custom "Why you should buy this" page if I feel that to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you submit your app it will have an app id viewable on iTunes Connect, use that id in your links and make a note for the reviewer that the link will work once other app is approved. This has worked for me. Also you can submit your app and choose to upload the binary later.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 7+

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id<APP ID>
```

It will open the app directly in the App Store

Answer (score 1):

You can submit your application, and then when your other applications get approved you "update" and include the links to those applications.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.itunes.com/app/AppName supposedly works. Not sure how it handles spaces or special characters, so you'd want to test that out if your app contains them.

Comment: Just tried: TwitterrificPremium links to Twitterrific Premium.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.itunes.com/app/AppName has worked for me. Similarly, you can swap AppName for ArtistName if you want to link to all the apps under the artist instead of the individual apps. Remember not to include any spaces between words!

Good luck!

Comment: So if i put the following from my app  http://www.itunes.com/app/AppName does it load the safari or the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is `itms://itunes.com/apps/AppName` if the SDK will let you, because that is what `http://itunes.com/apps/AppName` would redirect you to so it will open the iTunes / App Store app.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this mess easily with a remote redirection page. See at my blog: http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/archives/2010/11/03/Tangram_098_-_App_Store_link_to_the_full_versionreviews_before_even_submit_the_application/

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do would be to make your apps point to some URL under your own domain. Once you know the URLs for your apps for sure, you can make the URLs on your domain redirect to the App Store.

Then, you can update your apps to avoid the redirect…

You would probably want to use a UIWebView so that the redirect doesn't go from your app to Safari, then from Safari to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way now is to do the following:

1. Login to your **iTunes Connect**
2. Click My Apps then select your app
3. On the page that you are in (App information), scroll to the bottom and you should see a "View on App Store" Hyperlink like below. Right click and Copy Link Address and you are good to go :)

[image]