# iPhone sdk - open app store to specific app?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there a way to open the app store to a specific application?
I tried using something like the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=284417350&mt=8&uo=6"]];
```

But got the following: "Safari cannot open the page because to many redirects occurred".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Apparently this issue only affects the simulator. A build an go on the device works perfect.

Comment: I could imagine myself debugging my whole code not knowing that the problem is from the simulator... This answer seems better.

Answer (score 24):

Use http://itunes.com/app/YourAppNameWithoutSpaces

[See also this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513945/how-can-i-give-app-store-link-in-my-apps-before-approving-another-apps/1513954#1513954)

Comment: The same thing happens when the shorter URL is used.

Comment: I tried to be helpful, but you don't motivate people by downvoting a possibly helpful answer! I'll think twice the next time before answering a question of yours.

Comment: Sorry to downvote, my intent was not to demotivate, but rather if someone else has this issue and they read this post, it saves them from trying it.

Answer (score 7):

Another simple way is:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/YourAppNameWithoutSpaces"]];
```

This is very clean

Answer (score 5):

You can open app without opening safari

```
NSString *appId = @"you appid"; //like 999999999
NSString *link = [@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=" stringByAppendingString:appId];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:link]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace iTunesLink with your App URL.

```
 NSString *iTunesLink = @"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/digital-speedometer-pro/id1021728349?mt=8";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS 6 right way to go is using SKStoreProductViewController class.

Code is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32008404/1151916