# Add newly installed app to the list of accessible apps for launch

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Here is my scenario,  I'm coding an app let's call it app A, and I have already coded and published app B app C and app D with customized URL schemes.
Is this scenario for app A possible on IOS.

1. The app A will enable me to open the app store and shows only the
   apps that we developped (app B, app C and app D)
2. Then I select the app I wish and install it (let's say app B)
3. Once the installation of app B is over the app store closes and I'm redirected to a list where I have all the applications I installed
   (including the newly installed one app B
4. By clicking on the
   selected app I can launch it from my app A list

Answer (score 0):

1. You can open the App Store to a specific application using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517260/iphone-sdk-open-app-store-to-specific-app). I don't think you can open it to a preselected search for multiple applications.
2. Of course, this is normal functionality.
3. Under normal circumstances you can't determine what applications are installed.  In this case you might be able to use `-[UIApplication canOpenUrl:]` and your customized URL scheme to figure it out.
4. Under normal circumstances you can't directly open another application.  You could, however, use `-[UIApplication openUrl:]` and your customized scheme to do it.

Comment: Thanks David, how can I extract the URL scheme of my newly installed app just after installing it

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  I thought you already had the custom schemes implemented.

Comment: Yes me the developer I have it, but app A is designed for public audience they know nothing about my apps, all what they wish to do is select the app B for install and then see the app B on their list of installed apps