# how to add a link of other apps in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have a bunch of similar apps which the user might be interested in downloading.So when the user clicks on this button , it shows a link of other apps. Clicking on that link should take him to the download page in the app store. I tried google but couldn't find any answers.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517260/iphone-sdk-open-app-store-to-specific-app

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id230763487?mt=8"]];
```