# Getting the AppStore Link before publishing an App

Tags: iphone, app-store

I want to send an App link within the App like this:

http://itunes.apple.com/app/myiphoenapp/id373185673

The problem is, that I do not know the link in advance, because I haven't send the App to Apple yet.

I know that I can send the binary later, do I get the link then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [How can i give app store link in my apps before approving another apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513945/how-can-i-give-app-store-link-in-my-apps-before-approving-another-apps)
- [How to link to apps on the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store)
- [How can I link to my app in the App Store (iTunes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818973/iphone-how-can-i-include-a-url-to-my-app-in-the-app)

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Just create your iTunesConnect app entry early in production, so you'll have your App ID right from the beginning. You can setup metadata, add app binaries later on.

Creating App Store links worth a Googling on its own, as it varies a lot over time, accross different iOS versions.

---

You can solve this mess easily with a remote redirection page. See at my blog: http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/archives/2010/11/03/Tangram_098_-_App_Store_link_to_the_full_versionreviews_before_even_submit_the_application/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21814070)

Comment: Well, this is not the right answer anyway. I think the best is to create the bare bones iTunesConnect app entry early in production, so you'll have the App ID right away. Then you can setup all the metadata later on around release time.

Comment: I don't disagree. Why not click the edit button and add this information to your answer? Someone's heuristics flagged this answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://itunesconnect.apple.com
2. If you haven't created any app yet, create it.
3. Open it and in the first screen (AppStore -> App information -> General) there is a field called "Apple ID" with the id number.

[image]

4. http://itunes.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXXX
   and replace "XXXXXXXXX" with your "Apple ID" (from iTunes connect - after creating the app there)