# Obtain Apple software id number before appstore submission (for Appirater)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, appstore-approval, submission, app-id

I'd like to use the wonderful [Appirater](http://arashpayan.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/) code to encourage users to rate my app, which I have yet to submit. In order for this to work, you need to have the software id supplied by Apple. As I haven't yet submitted my app, I don't have this id number. I do of course have my Bundle Seed ID and Bundle Identifier but my understanding is that these are not the same. Is it possible to obtain the software id before submission? Or will I have to update the app as soon as it is released?

Thanks,

Michael.

Comment: This asks a similar question, but the solution may not be appropriate for this situation: [How can i give app store link in my apps before approving another apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513945/how-can-i-give-app-store-link-in-my-apps-before-approving-another-apps)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To get your software id from Apple, log into iTunesConnect and go through the process of submitting your app. Essentially, perform every step except the binary upload. At that point, you'll have an Apple ID for your app, which you can use in Appirater.

You can always go back and change the app description text or keywords before you've uploaded the binary, so don't worry about being locked into anything (other than the SKU) when you go through this process.

-Arash

Comment: From the man himself I assume. Thanks! And thanks for the code :)

Comment: Thanks - great class and that's a really useful tip