# How can I predict my APP ID in the app store before submitting?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-id

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obtain Apple software id number before appstore submission (for Appirater)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153186/obtain-apple-software-id-number-before-appstore-submission-for-appirater)

I want to remind users to rate my app, like what's done in https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater

For that, I need to know what my APP ID is going to be (so I could update the link to the rating page).

Is there a way to know that before my app is in the App Store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply don't upload your binary until you are given an App ID when you submit your app, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4153186/840973).

Comment: that's what I suspected, thanks!