# rate app button

Tags: ios

i am trying to understand the required code to rate my app.
i have my rate me button ( not apple's menu) which i need it to take the user to my app in the itunes store .

i have seen this :

```
http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=000000000
```

and that i have to put my app id instead the 0000..
BUT the app id - i can get only after my app is in the store !

so , how would i insert the right url to my app to rate it before release ?

thanks .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain Apple software id number before appstore submission (for Appirater)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153186/obtain-apple-software-id-number-before-appstore-submission-for-appirater)

Comment: i have seen that but this is a strange thing to do- just to get this id a moment before release and open your code and insert that, WITHOUT knowing if its going to work in real,or there will be some kind of bug .

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are assigned an appId once you create your app in iTunesConnect. You should be assigned an appId before submitting. Once you get that far, you should be able to replace 0000 with your new appId.

Comment: Bill is correct, you get your id when you create your app in iTunesConnect.

Comment: but how can i check that it works before release my app ??

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Appirater library found [here](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater). It is under the MIT/X11 license, which means you can use it in commercial apps. 
Here's a description of it from the Github page:

> Appirater is a class that you can drop into any iPhone app (iOS 4.0 or later) that will help remind your users to review your app on the App Store.

Hope this helps!