# How to know the App ID from the App Store before distributing the version 1.0 of an App with Xcode?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, app-id

I would like to know my App ID from the App Store, before distributing the App.

I'm deploying a new target of an App, and I would like to know the App ID from the App Store, in order to give my users a link to rate the App.

I know that I can get the App ID very easily, once it is distributed, from the App Store Connect website. But I would like to know if it's possible to know the ID before deploying the new target for the first time. (Version 1.0 - Bundle (1)

It's not the biggest problem in the world, but I'm curious about it.

I'm using Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61), and the language is objective-C

My idea is to insert the ID in a URL string (depending on the target I'm using), to send the user to my App inside the App Store.

An example:

First I chose the App target

```
    if ([appName isEqualToString:@"myAmazingApp"]) {
        sharedGlobalData.AppId  = @"6XXXXXXX9";
}
```

Then somewhere a button to send the user to the AppStore.

```
(IBAction)rateApp:(id)sender {
    NSString * myAmazingAppl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id%@?mt=8",[SingletonClass sharedGlobalData].AppId];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: myAmazingAppID]];
}
```

By now, I'm just raw copy-pasting the App ID from the App Store Connect web site into the string variable, but only once the App is distributed, so the 1.0 version is always without knowing the ID.

I would like to get a more "elegant" way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtain Apple software id number before appstore submission (for Appirater)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153186/obtain-apple-software-id-number-before-appstore-submission-for-appirater)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just create a new entry in [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com) and you will get the app id in the "App Information" menu item (under "General Information"/"Apple ID").

You don't need to have the first version of your app distributed, this id won't change.